# Cakephp : How to set my project url to my domain?

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

For example http://example.com/ is my domain and when I visit this, it will show cakephp framework home page with five green messages.
I have to type http://example.com/index.php/public/index to get to my project's home page

What should I do to get my project running on my domain's main url http://example.com/

I am using CakePHP 2.7.1

Thanks in advance

Comment: if `/index.php` is in the url at all - there's something wrong with your app setup (or you're not using modrewrite, which should be stated in the question).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can define a route in routes.php in Config Folder like this

```
   Router::connect('/', array('controller' => 'public', 'action' => 'index'));
```

This will redirect your main url to the desired controller

Comment: @Vky If you want to say "thank you," vote on or [accept](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) that person's answer. Further read [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)